# How to plot a lattice (2D or 3D) given a basis

Tags: graphics, linear-algebra, algebra

I want a graphical picture of a lattice with basis such as $\{(1,1), (\sqrt{2}, -\sqrt{2})\}$. Does *Mathematica* already have a pre-made function that finds all linear combinations over $\mathbb{Z}$ for a given basis? This just amounts to a linear transformation of the regular $\mathbb{Z}^2$ lattice. Is it much different for 3D?

Comment: "a pre-made function that finds all linear combinations" - it doesn't have one IIRC, but it should not be too hard to write one.

Comment: also have a look at [LatticeData](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LatticeData.html).

Comment: Yeah. I mean I looked at the function LatticeData[{"IntegerLattice", 2}, "Image"]. Cannot return a picture .... MISSING ... AVAILBILITY. Using 9.0 version

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is a solution for the 2D case.

```
lattice[basis : {Repeated[{_Real, _Real}, {2}]}, 
        nX_Integer?Positive, nY_Integer?Positive] :=
 Module[{box, sides},
   box = Sort /@ Transpose[basis];
   sides = Flatten[Abs[Differences[#]] & /@ box];
   Flatten[CoordinateBoundsArray[box, sides, 0, {{0, nX - 1}, {0, nY - 1}}], 1]]

With[{basis = {{1, 1}, Sqrt[2] {1, -1}} // N}, 
  Graphics[{Point[lattice[basis, 4, 2]], Red, Line[basis]}, Frame -> True]]
```

[image: lattice]

Answer (score 0):

```
LatticeData["FaceCenteredCubic", "Image"]
```

[image]

and try:  `LatticeData[#, "Image"] & /@ LatticeData[3]`

Comment: Not the lattices the OP had in mind, I'm sure.

Comment: OP? What goes in the #? I have seen this on the Wolfram reference page, but it is just a command ... you can't manipulate it to what you want.

Comment: # is the placeholder for a variable in a function.  #^2 & is the square function.  You must read basic *Mathematica* to progress here; otherwise our solutions will be mysteries to you.